# Como passo uma variavel do Banco de dados que está em php para javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Eu tenho um programa que tem coordenadas no Banco de dados, tá pegando essas coordenadas eu passsaria para uma outra pagina(javascript) que calcularia a rota e mostraria um mapa na tela do usuarios(pelo ip) para um estabelecimento(coordenadas). Mas para passar precisarei usar ajax, como não sei alguem poderia me dar uma luz??

Comment: Não tem como passar uma variável em si de uma aplicação para outra. E nos ajuda se você fornecer algum fonte, nós não somos um serviço de escrita de código.

Comment: @LucasCosta Ele não quis dizer exatamente "variável", creio eu. Nesse caso de AJAX o JavaScript faz uma requisição assíncrona para um URL e recebe o conteúdo da resposta da requisição. O mesmo conteúdo pode ser interpretado, por exemplo, como JSON, qualquer coisa.

Comment: Sim @Someone, uma edição com o título mais sugestivo para que outras pessoas possam encontrar a questão mais fácil e algum código é bem vinda.

Comment: Só pra esclarecer, AJAX trabalha com JSON, string e XML.

Answer (score 0):

Não é assim que funciona: passar uma *"variável"* de um código em execução para outro (e que ainda funciona totalmente diferente um do outro, ainda mais por uma requisição). Uma requisição AJAX (assíncrona) é feita para um URL específico, e recebe uma cadeia de caracteres como resposta (que por padrão pode ser interpretada pela presença de um cabeçalho na requisição) do conteúdo desse URL.

Para começar, o PHP deve responder o client-side com as coordenadas. Já que vai haver mais do que um valor e a resposta do server-side é uma cadeia de caracteres vai ser preciso usar uma lógica de separação. Nesse caso, codificar o que armazena essas coordenadas como JSON pode ser útil. Se essas coordenadas estão visíveis numa (array) (PHP, diferente do JS), o JSON de resultado poderia ser algo assim:

```
"[coordenada1, coordenada2, ...]"
```

Usando `json_encode` no PHP. Para responder o client-side basta utilizar `echo` (acho que também dá para usar `print` e `printf`, embora eu não sei muito do PHP para dizer isso).

```
echo json_encode(suasCoordenadas);
```

Para interpretar o JSON pode ser utilizado `JSON.parse` no JavaScript. `eval` ou `Function#` (ou seja, o próprio JavaScript!) também podem ser utilizados, e não há insegurança alguma em relação ao servidor, só é ruím depender da linguagem em sí.

Exemplo para fazer uma requisição assíncrona no JavaScript, utilizando `XMLHttpRequest`

```
var handleRequestError,
    handleRequestResponse,
    request;

handleRequestError = status =>
    alert(status);

handleRequestResponse = data =>
    alert(JSON.parse(data)[0]);

request = new XMLHttpRequest;

// Primeiro parâmetro de XHR#open:
// --- é o método utilizado na requisição.

// Terceiro parâmetro:
// --- diz se a requisição é síncrona;
// --- padrão: true, ou false em outros navegadores

// Últimos parâmetros:
// --- Nome de usuário e senha (restrição)

request.open('get', 'file.php', true);

// O evento "readystatechange" do XHR
// ocorre quando o estado da requisição
// muda.
request.onreadystatechange = () => {
    // XHR#readyState, o estado.
    // Se o estado for 4, a requisição
    // está feita.
    // Outra equivalência é utilizar o evento "load",
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load
    if (request.readyState === 4) {
        // XHR#status: estática

        // Sucesso?
        request.status === 200 ?
          // XHR#responseText: resposta em texto
          // XHR#response retorna a resposta com um valor
          // dependente de #responseType
          // E XHR#responseType funciona antes de a
          // requisição iniciar (ou terminar)
          handleRequestResponse(request.responseText)
                               :
          handleRequestError(request.status);
    }
};

request.send();
```

Lembrando que: isso não é tudo; se quiser saber mais do `XMLHttpRequest` veja outros assuntos.